# predictive effect in the classification made according to the comments in different fields

Tags: nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I want to do a classification through comments categorized in 4 areas. For example, categorizing the product as good or bad based on the comments in the fields X, Y, Z, M. How can I follow a path to see the effects of these 4 areas on the result. It was first to combine the comments in the 4 fields, then to predict via lstm, but the separation of the fields is lost. Would it be a good solution to build and combine 4 different models?

Comment: First, this is a design question so it would be better asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Also the question not clear to me: what is the input and output? i.e. is it about how to predict these 4 areas, or is it about combining these 4 areas into "the result"? And what is supposed to be this result? Maybe you could give an example of what you expect to obtain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.